# Unable to have two-word-search in Zsh's TAB completion for Man

Tags: search, zsh, zsh-completion

**Problem:** to have a tab completion which takes two words and calculates the best match from them for Man, and then returns the best matches

**Example:** The following pseudo-code should give me at least Zsh's reverse-menu-complete -command. Right now, I cannot search manuals inside manuals without zgrep.

```
man zsh:reverse <TAB>
```

where ":" is the separator which I want.

**Initial Problem:** Which files does the TAB completion run when I press TAB for one word in searching manuals by Zsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will attempt to provide an insight to how zsh completion system works and an incomplete go at this problem.

The file that runs when you use TAB completion for `man` in zsh is located under the `/usr/share/zsh/${ZSH_VERSION}/functions` directory. The tree varies across distributions, but the file is named `_man`, and provides completion for `man`, `apropos` and `whatis`.

After _man is invoked, it works as following (rough description):

1. if completing for `man` and `--local-file` was specified as first flag, invoke standard files completion (`_files`)
2. construct `manpath` variable from a set of defaults / `$MANPATH`. This is where the manpages will be searched
3. determine if we invoked `man` with a section number parameter, if yes - only those sections will be searched
4. if the `zstyle ':completion:*:manuals' separate-sections true` was used, separate sections in output (don't mix between them)
5. invoke `_man_pages` to provide a list of man pages for the match
6. `_man_pages` now does a bit of magic with `compfiles -p pages '' '' "$matcher" '' dummy '*'`. `pages` is the variable with all the directories containing manpages for requested section(s). The actual globbing pattern is constructed from the implicit parameter `$PREFIX` and the last parameter to `compfiles` - `*` in this case. This results in `/usr/share/man/man1` to be transformed into `/usr/share/man/man1/foo*`
7. The new list of glob patterns is globbed, obtaining all files which match the pattern
8. `_man_pages` then strips any suffixes from the files and adds them to the completion widget list of choices by using `compadd`

Now, as you can see, the list of manpages is directly determined by `$PREFIX` variable. In order to make `zsh:foo` to list only man pages of `zsh*` which contain the word `foo`, it needs to be split across `:` character (if any).

The following addition in `_man_pages` partially solve the issue (zsh 4.3.4):

Original:

```
_man_pages() {
  local matcher pages dummy sopt

  zparseopts -E M+:=matcher

  if (( $#matcher )); then
    matcher=( ${matcher:#-M} )
    matcher="$matcher"
  else
    matcher=
  fi

  pages=( ${(M)dirs:#*$sect/} )

  compfiles -p pages '' '' "$matcher" '' dummy '*'
  pages=( ${^~pages}(N:t) )

  (($#mrd)) && pages[$#pages+1]=($(awk $awk $mrd))

  # Remove any compression suffix, then remove the minimum possible string
  # beginning with .<->: that handles problem cases like files called
  # `POSIX.1.5'.

  [[ $OSTYPE = solaris* ]] && sopt='-s '
  if ((CURRENT > 2)) ||
      ! zstyle -t ":completion:${curcontext}:manuals.$sect" insert-sections
  then
    compadd "$@" - ${pages%.(?|<->*(|.gz|.bz2|.Z))}
  else
    compadd "$@" -P "$sopt$sect " - ${pages%.(?|<->*(|.gz|.bz2|.Z))}
  fi
}
```

Modified (look for ##mod comments):

```
_man_pages() {
  local matcher pages dummy sopt

  zparseopts -E M+:=matcher

  if (( $#matcher )); then
    matcher=( ${matcher:#-M} )
    matcher="$matcher"
  else
    matcher=
  fi

  pages=( ${(M)dirs:#*$sect/} )

  ##mod
  # split components by the ":" character
  local pref_words manpage_grep orig_prefix
  # save original prefix (just in case)
  orig_prefix=${PREFIX}
  # split $PREFIX by ':' and make it an array
  pref_words=${PREFIX//:/ }
  set -A pref_words ${=pref_words}
  # if there are both manpage name and grep string, use both
  if (( $#pref_words == 2 )); then
      manpage_grep=$pref_words[2]
      # PREFIX is used internally by compfiles
      PREFIX=$pref_words[1]
  elif (( $#pref_words == 1 )) && [[ ${PREFIX[1,1]} == ":" ]]; then
      # otherwise, prefix is empty and only grep string exists
      PREFIX=
      manpage_grep=$pref_words[1]
  fi


  compfiles -p pages '' '' "$matcher" '' dummy '*'
  ##mod: complete, but don't strip path names
  pages=( ${^~pages} )

  (($#mrd)) && pages[$#pages+1]=($(awk $awk $mrd))

  ##mod: grep pages
  # Build a list of matching pages that pass the grep
  local matching_pages
  typeset -a matching_pages

  # manpage_grep exists and not empty 
  if (( ${#manpage_grep} > 0 )); then
      for p in ${pages}; do
          zgrep "${manpage_grep}" $p > /dev/null
          if (( $? == 0 )); then
              #echo "$p matched $manpage_grep"
              matching_pages+=($p)
          fi
      done
  else
  # there's no manpage_grep, so all pages match
      matching_pages=( ${pages} )
  fi

  #echo "\nmatching manpages: "${matching_pages}
  pages=( ${matching_pages}(N:t) )
  # keep the stripped prefix for now
  #PREFIX=${orig_prefix}


  # Remove any compression suffix, then remove the minimum possible string
  # beginning with .<->: that handles problem cases like files called
  # `POSIX.1.5'.


  [[ $OSTYPE = solaris* ]] && sopt='-s '
  if ((CURRENT > 2)) ||
      ! zstyle -t ":completion:${curcontext}:manuals.$sect" insert-sections
  then
    compadd "$@" - ${pages%.(?|<->*(|.gz|.bz2|.Z))}
  else
    compadd "$@" -P "$sopt$sect " - ${pages%.(?|<->*(|.gz|.bz2|.Z))}
  fi
}
```

However, it's still not fully working (if you uncomment the `#echo "$p matched $manpage_grep"` line, you can see that it does build the list) - I suspect that somewhere internally, the completion system sees that, for instance, "zshcompctl" is not matched by prefix "zsh:foo", and does not display the resulting matches. I've tried to keep `$PREFIX` as it is after stripping the grep string, but it still does not want to work.

At any rate, this at least should get you started.